# Magic number in Data Explorer should be documented

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, data-explorer

There are several columns such as `Posts.PostTypeId` where the content are encoded as an integer. Although not hard to find out playing with a few queries, what these integers represent should be documented, and shown in or linked from the schema.

Comment: you know what would be nice, if on hover it would display a tooltip with information about the column beyond the data type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data dump schema is well-documented in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/anatomy-of-a-data-dump), including all the magic numbers. It doesn't include the normalized tables, but that should be obvious when looking at the Data Explorer schema.

The vote types are available by querying the VoteTypes table, but the post types are not. Personally, I would like to see the post types normalized just like the vote types, so you don't have to refer back to another website to find out the values (particularly if a 3rd value is added down the road).

**EDIT:** There is now a PostTypeId = 3 for Tag Wiki entries, so it's even more desirable for this column to be normalized. If the same Ids are maintained as the primary key in a PostTypes table, this shouldn't break any (many?) of the queries.

**EDIT:** I have added [PostTypes](https://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/source/detail?r=e4b4987ddfe6c0a0bd2ee7d7bf454b5e68b37f04) and [PostHistoryTypes](https://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/source/detail?r=e6e5ab05a7540cf9fe9ba7716e2e989141a059a8) to the schema. This will be live the next data dump import to SEDE (Jan 2011).

Comment: This is now live. The Area 51 vote types are not included in this iteration.

Answer (score 11):

An unofficial documentation on the value of these columns:

- **Posts.PostTypeId**

  These should be obtained by `SELECT * FROM PostTypes`.

  - 1 = Questions
  - 2 = Answers
  - 3 = Tag wiki (from the early days, before separate excerpts)
  - 4 = Tag wiki excerpt
  - 5 = Tag wiki
  - 6 = Moderator election candidate platforms
  - 7 = Moderator-editable part of the site FAQ, and moderator election announcements (SE 2.0 only)
  - 8 = Privilege pages (`/privileges/NAME`) (Meta.SO only)
- **PostHistory.PostHistoryTypeId**

  These should be obtained by `SELECT * FROM PostHistoryTypes`.

  - 1 = Initial Title - The first title a question is asked with.
  - 2 = Initial Body - The first raw body text a post is submitted with.
  - 3 = Initial Tags - The first tags a question is asked with.
  - 4 = Edit Title - A question's title has been changed.
  - 5 = Edit Body - A post's body has been changed, the raw text is stored here as markdown.
  - 6 = Edit Tags - A question's tags have been changed.
  - 7 = Rollback Title - A question's title has reverted to a previous version.
  - 8 = Rollback Body - A post's body has reverted to a previous version - the raw text is stored here.
  - 9 = Rollback Tags - A question's tags have reverted to a previous version.
  - 10 = Post Closed
  - 11 = Post Reopened
  - 12 = Post Deleted
  - 13 = Post Undeleted
  - 14 = Post Locked
  - 15 = Post Unlocked
  - 16 = Community Owned - A post has become community owned.
  - 17 = Post Migrated - A post was migrated.
  - 18 = Question Merged - A question has had another, deleted question merged into itself.
  - 19 = Question Protected
  - 20 = Question Unprotected
  - 21 = Post Disassociated - An admin removes the OwnerUserId from a post.
  - 22 = Question Unmerged - A previously merged question has had its answers and votes restored.
  - 24 = Approved suggested edit.
- **Votes.VoteTypeId**

  These should be obtained by `SELECT * FROM VoteTypes`.

  - 1 = AcceptedByOriginator
  - 2 = UpMod
  - 3 = DownMod
  - 4 = Offensive
  - 5 = Favorite
  - 6 = Close
  - 7 = Reopen
  - 8 = BountyStart
  - 9 = BountyClose
  - 10 = Deletion
  - 11 = Undeletion
  - 12 = Spam
  - 13 = InformModerator
  - 15 = ??
  - 16 = Approved suggested edit

  If Area51 is to be included:

  - 2 = On-topic
  - 3 = Off-topic
  - 22 = Meh-vote
  - 23 = Referral in commitment phase
  - 28 = Fulfilled commitment (you or referral)

Comment: Citation for vote types 22 and 23?

Comment: @Jon: http://area51.stackexchange.com/reputation

Comment: Ah yes. I didn't think of that.

Comment: Note also that PostTypeId is (currently) redundant with Questions having a NULL ParentId and for Answers ParentId is not NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Until there is official documentation, you can refer to Brent Ozar's [Understanding the StackOverflow Database Schema](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Understanding_the_StackOverflow_Database_Schema).